# How to create a primary key using sqlalchemy of type 'generated always as identity'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, ddl

I'm using postgres, and want to create the SQLA model for the following DDL:

```sql
create table tbl(
    tbl_id INT generated always as identity PRIMARY KEY, 
    tbl_x  INT
)
```

How to create this table using sqlalchemy ?

Answer (score 1):

```py
#...
from sqlalchemy import Identity
#...

tbl = Table('tbl', metadata_obj,
    Column('tbl_id', Integer, Identity(always=True))
    Column('tbl_x', Integer),
)
```

[See:Identity](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Identity)